# Exploring Google Material

Tags: material-design

While exploring Google Material, I have learned the new science of designing. But did not found the proper source to learn how to use it.

I tried to find a lot but did not find a good source for learning Google Material Design for Web. Please provide some useful URLs so that I can start exploring this.

Good jsfiddle examples can also help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Google Material", exactly? Google's "Material Design" aka Quantum Paper ?

Comment: I found this question useful. Sad, someone blocked it ... ! Really idiot ppl.

Comment: @enkryptor Yes, I mean Google's "Material Design" aka Quantum Paper by google Material. Its so hard to find some good tutorial for this. It was so easy to use Bootstrap as a well document and Reference sheet is provided.

Comment: @Peterson 

They might not liked the way of asking the question :(

Comment: Anyways, atleast I found your question useful buddy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary source for "how to use" a design are design guidelines. You can found them at [the official website](https://design.google.com/resources/).

Also, you can use existing implementations, for instance, [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/).

Comment: Just like Bootstrap, do we have a complete document to use Google Material Design? Here on the provided link, I just find the Concepts. No implementation Tutorials. 

On Twitter Bootstrap Website, I found enough of Examples to properly use it.

Comment: I think you're messing things up. Bootstrap is a framework, or collection of HTML/CSS templates. It has differently stylized skins. On the contrary, Material Design is a collection of design guidelines. It just tells you, how things should look like; the implementation is all up to you.

Comment: @Spidi'sWeb you can use existing implementations, e.g. http://www.material-ui.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have cleared a big misconception of mine.